# L'emploi « délocutif » et les « verbes de Benveniste » : explications ?

Tags: vocabulaire, verbes, terminologie, linguistique, dictionnaires

On a l'interjection « [fi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fi) » surtout connue dans l'emploi « délocutif » *faire fi de*. Au GDT on a le terme *délocutif* employé pour traduire deux termes distincts en langue anglaise ([*delocutional verb*](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=17065722), [*locution-based derivative*](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=17065723)).

> (Définition 1 :) Verbe dérivé d'une locution et dénotant une activité du
>   discours (selon Benveniste).
>
> (Définition 2 :) [Dénominatif](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9nominatif) [autonymique](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/autonymique) qui s'applique aux verbes
>   délocutifs de Benveniste, et aux autres parties du discours que le
>   verbe, dérivées d'une base autonyme.
>
> [ Grand dictionnaire terminologique de l'OQLF, 2 définitions pour «
>   délocatif » ]

Dans les deux cas c'est suivi essentiellement de la même note que voici :

> Mais Benveniste ne voit pas que/dire : salut/ et /dire : tu/ sont des
>   phrases [métalinguistiques](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/m%C3%A9talinguistique), salut signifiant « le mot salut » et tu «
>   le mot tu », c'est-à-dire étant des mots autonymes et par conséquent
>   tous des noms (/ce tu m'agace, pourquoi ne me vouvoie-t-il pas? /).
>   Donc délocutif est inexact puisque tu est un nom; le « délocutif
>   » n'est pas forcément un verbe (ex. : un jemenfoutiste (celui qui dit
>   je m'en fous). D'ailleurs « locution » est chez Benveniste un emploi
>   bizarre qui ne correspond à rien d'actuel en français (latinisme?).
>   Courant dans un des domaines techniques ou scientifiques.
>
> [ Grand dictionnaire terminologique de l'OQLF, note commune aux deux
>   vedettes « délocatif » ]

- Peut-on expliquer la nuance entre les deux définitions : est-ce
  simplement que l'une s'applique uniquement aux verbes et l'autre à un
  ensemble plus vaste ; la note permet-elle de répondre à la question :
  peut-on simplifier son propos ?
- Quels sont « les verbes délocutifs de Benveniste » ; y a-t-il une liste finie ?
- Peut-on illustrer avec un ou des exemples ; par exemple si dans un texte on lisait que quelqu'un « exprime ses salutations* (« il lui exprima ses salutations »), s'agirait-il d'un « emploi délocutif » pour « [salut](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/salut) ! » ?
- Incidemment, l'*autonymie* et la *métonymie* sont-elles similaires ?

Comment: Un jem'enfoutiste n'est pas une personne qui dit « je m'en fou » ; (définition du TLFi : Personne qui manifeste une totale indifférence à l'égard de ce qui devrait normalement l'intéresser, à l'égard de toute chose ou de tout le monde.) Quelque chose comme « celui qui est indifférent à tout » serait approprié.

Comment: @LPH [D'accord](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/je-m'en-foutiste) mais là n'est pas la question, qui porte sur la linguistique et pas sur le sens actuel de ce mot. Par ailleurs ça [dérive](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/je%20m'en%20fous) clairement de ce que veut dire la personne qui ça, d'où la présentation du terme dans ce contexte...

Comment: Oui, je vois, c'est la mention de  l'origine du délocutif ; alors il faudrait nuancer cela de la façon suivante : « celui dont l'attitude est celle de ceux qui disent « je m'en fous »».

Comment: Bon, ça va, ça va, ne vous énervez pas, j'essayerai de me rappeler que lorsqu'on vous lit il faut parfois lire n'importe quoi et trouver ça normal.

Comment: Toute cette abondante fourniture de liens dans vos questions constitue-elle une présentation si concise des choses ? Je ne m'en plains pas quand je peux l'utiliser, on ne peut pas être précis en peu de mots ; d'ailleurs vos questions sont toujours énormément longues en comparaison à celles de n'importe qui ; il y a bien une raison pour cela ; c'est que vous insistez sur beaucoup de détail et de précision ; je fais de même dans mes réponses, ou du moins je fais de mon mieux dans ce sens.

Comment: @LPH _Fair enough_, c'est de bonne guerre.